# Laravel eloquent return multiple values on first

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to return 1 row and get only couple column values of it:

```
public static function getLastUpdate(){
    return Settings::where('item', 'lastUpdate')->first()->value('item', 'created_at');
}
```

gives only value for 'item'.

pluck() not working here (gives new query on all table)

$hidden not good, since i'm using couple methods in same model.

didnt find in laravel docs.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static function getLastUpdate(){
    return Settings::where('item', 'lastUpdate')->first(['item', 'created_at']);
}

$setting = getLastUpdate();
echo $setting->item;
echo $setting->created_at;
```

Comment: tried, but for some reason not worked for me. 
may be made some mistake.
thanks